# IOS - Como programar a navegação entre ViewController em Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, xcode

Quero navegar entre as ViewController de um app, clicando em um botão e alternando de uma pra outra por exemplo. Mas não queria fazer isso pela .storyboard, quero fazer direto via código. É possivel? Se sim, como posso fazer.

Comment: Você quer também criar `UIViewController` pelo código ou elas virão da sua *storyboard*?

Comment: Vai vir da storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar os métodos [`pushViewController:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:) ou [`presentViewController:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:). Primeiro você precisa obter uma instância da sua `UIViewController` que será aberta e que está na *storyboard* através do identificador:

```
SegundaViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"segundaView"];
```

Agora você faz o *push* a partir do `navigationController`:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Ou abrir como um modal:

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado, porem se uso dentro da viewDidLoad ele não funciona.
Sabe como posso resolver isto?

Comment: Você pretende que logo que abrir uma tela, executar este código para abrir outra?

Comment: Sim, no caso, a tela inicial é um cadastro, porem, eu verifico nela se o cliente já foi cadastrado, se sim, queria mandá-lo direto pra tela inicial do app.

Comment: Se for possível, mesmo o trecho do seu código que está no `viewDidLoad`. Mas como se trata de outra pergunta, sugiro criar uma nova questão só para esta dúvida.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115759/ios-como-programar-a-navega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-viewcontroller-direto-na-viewdidload