# IOS - Como programar a navegação entre ViewController direto na viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, xcode

Quero navegar entre as ViewController de um app, clicando em um botão e alternando de uma pra outra por exemplo. Queria executar isso direto na viewDidLoad da ViewController1, se o usuário já se cadastrou, mando ele pra segundaView.

Seria algo assim:

## ViewController1

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    if(_cadastrado isEqualToString:@"1"){
        UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"segundaView"];
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

O método quando executo fora da viewDidLoad funciona perfeitamente, porem, quando tento executar ele dentro da viewDidLoad não consigo.

Comment: Tenta colocar dentro da `viewDidAppear`, pois você só pode fazer chamadas de telas após a view atual já esta sendo exibida

Comment: Estou tentando aqui, logo aviso se consegui.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado Jeferson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a dica de @JeffersonAssis, consegui incluindo o código mencionado na pergunta dentro do método **viewDidAppear**.

ficou desta forma:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if(_cadastrado isEqualToString:@"1"){
        UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"segundaView"];
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Assim, ele executa logo após ter executado toda a **viewDidLoad**.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, neste caso sera necessário efetuar este processo no AppDelegate

Exemplo Este:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // EM - Implementação da verificação do cadastro da função do Device
    NSIndexPath * indexPath;

    [PlistManager deletePlist:@"ServerControllerPWD" location:@"doc"];

    Password * passConference = [[PWDataController sharedInstance].PWData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([passConference.functionVC isEqualToString:@"Servidor"]) {

        ServerViewController *appStartViewController = [[ServerViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appStartViewController];
        [navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Server"];
        self.window.rootViewController = vc;

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    } else {

     nil ;

return YES;

}
```

Este exemplo está pegando os dados de um objeto que tem os dados armazenado em um Plist.

Que efetua esta comparação se existe dados ou não, se existe dados ele abre a tela de cadastro, se há dados ele abre a view referente.

No seu caso este **"_cadastro"** se refere a que ?

Comment: Olá Elias, no caso o  ** _Cadastro**  é uma NSString e seu conteúdo é um resultado que me avisa se o usuário foi ou não cadastrado, minha dúvida era a troca de tela mesmo. Mas consegui adicionando meu código que citei na pergunta dentro do método 'viewDidAppear' citado pelo @Jefferson Assis

Comment: Isso, desta forma também é funcional, que bom ter conseguido! abraços!